# Clean way to implement messagebox pattern in react

Tags: reactjs, design-patterns

Is there a clean way to implement a message box pattern in react like so?

```
import MessageBox from "MessageBox";

class MyComponent {
    render () {...}
    onDeleteButtonClick = async (data) => {

      let result = await  MessageBox.show("Delete?", "Sure you want to delete   this?", MessageBox.Buttons.OkCancel);

      if(result === MessageBox.Result.Ok) {
        deleteThing(data);
      }

    }
```

There does not seem to be a way to this without resorting to refs, breaking promise rules (making deferreds), or doing DOM trickery (having a wrapper that renders a component).

I built a component that followed my API above, except with a callback, but it required a ref and felt like I wasn't building things the react way.

Comment: what exactly is the problem with your code here?

Comment: @dfsq - There is no problem. The code is an example of a MessageBox api I would like to write, that doesn't use refs, deferreds, or out of the box dom manipulation. I feel like I'm repeating my original post, did you read it?

Comment: have you tried using portal ?? https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html, I tend to use it most of the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can render a message box inside your `MyComponent`. With `fixed` positioning nobody sees where in the document tree the box was defined. By this, you avoid node refs or a global state mechanism like Redux.

You can supply the click handlers to the `MessageBox` as props, but it may be even nicer to provide a `buttons` *render prop* in the `MessageBox` component, like below. This way, `MessageBox` has complete control over the rendering and `MyComponent` has complete control over the functionality.

```
import MessageBox from './MessageBox'

class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  onDeleteButtonClick(data) => {
    this.setState({ data, messageBoxOpen: true })
  }

  onMessageOkClick() => {
    deleteThing(this.state.data)
    this.setState({ messageBoxOpen: false })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      // ...content...
      <button onClick={this.onDeleteButtonClick}>delete</button>
      // more content
      <MessageBox
        open={this.state.messageBoxOpen}
        text="Question?"
        buttons={(Button) => [
          <Button text="Ok" onClick={this.onMessageOkClick} />,
          <Button text="Cancel" onClick={this.setState({ messageBoxOpen: false })} />
        ]}
      />
    )
  }
}

// MessageBox.jsx

const Button = ({ text, onClick }) => { /* ... */ }

const MessageBox = ({ open, text, buttons }) => open ? (
  <div>
    {text}
    {buttons(Button)}
  </div>
) : null
```

Comment: Thanks I tried that pattern, but it needs to be triggered from another event, see my onDeleteButtonClick. After user confirms delete ok, I want to delete using data param. How would I hang onto that without making it an instance var? I'm trying to make it work like window.confirm basically

Comment: @user210757 Well that's easy. :) See my newly added `onDeleteButtonClick`

Comment: I like this a lot, I'm trying to understand render props. New to react, if you haven't noticed!

Comment: Thanks, this is awesome, just what I was looking for. Learned a few things - render props, and passing jsx elements as an array so you don't have to wrap in containing element (buttons). My case I don't use the Button argument on the render function, I didn't really get that. I'm importing a react-bootstrap button in MyComponent and using it there

Comment: Good to hear that! The `Button` argument can be used when you want to provide a custom button element from the message box to the message box users, so that the rendering of the button is entirely in control of the message box component. This separation of rendering and functionality is key in render props, but if you use the same buttons throughout your app than this doesn't matter of course.

Answer (score 1):

I’ve almost always seen this pattern implemented using redux, I’ll explain it that way because I think is the most chosen method by the community.

You can implement a message box using `redux`. You instantiate the message box component at your apps source
**App.js**

```
<div>
  <Main />
  <MessageModal />
</div>
```

Being the **reducer state** of MessageModal:

```
{
open: true|false,
props: {}|{...}
}
```

Then you just import the *open/close action* of the message box and use it wherever you need it ( Components /Sagas)

Other option might be using [react’s context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Comment: Thank you for the great suggestions. I do have redux hooked up but wanted to keep this simple. Let me look into context

Comment: I think that redux may be the right choice. It is simple and straightforward if you do it right. Why do you think it is complicated?

Comment: I just didn't want to require redux for this, I'd like it to be a standalone solution that could be used in projects without redux.